# Resources for learning assembly on ti MSP430G2553

Tags: assembly, msp430

Im current in a class in my university that is teaching us assembly for the MSP430 launchpad. Im struggling a bit with learning it as it is very different from the other languages Im used to looking at, and the class isnt taught too well, at least for me. Its my understanding that Assembly is different for each piece of hardware, but is this at the family or group level, so would all MSP430's be the same or is the g2553 different than the other MSP430 boards in terms of Assembly language?

Do you have any recommendation for resources where I could learn the right Assembly language, good sample programs to test and look through to learn and get used to memory locations etc, and good projects to try to get better at it? Again the board we are using is the MSP430G2553.

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: The available instructions and CPU registers are "per CPU type", so if all MSP boards use the same CPU, instructions for programming will be same. (I did a quick google and that's one huge family, probably having also minor CPU differences between generations, but they will be no big deal). The environment the CPU sees around will be different. From trivial changes like having only 256B of RAM instead of 4kiB RAM, through medium (maybe whole memory mapped to different addresses) to completely new peripherals available (each peripheral device has it's own way of controlling it = driver code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All MSP430 use the same instruction set. The ones that exceed 64-KB of address space additionally support the MSP430X extension that lets you use memory up to 1MB.

https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf is the guide for MSP430x2xx, which contains the instruction set. https://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Category:MSP430 is the page that has links to the resources provided by TI. If you are blocked by the server, you can use the Internet Archive. https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf

Also see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430).